# How to get day wise records of particular month in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is my schema

```
empname: {type: String},
soldby: {type: String},
expenseprice:{type:Number},
expensedesc:{type:String},
expensetype:{type:String},
createdat: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

I tried this query

```
db.expenses.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            year: { $year: "$createdat" },
            month: { $month: "$createdat" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdat" },
            expenseprice: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
           _id: {
              year: "$year",
              month: "$month",
              day: "$day"
           },
           sum: { $sum: "$expenseprice" }
        }
    }
])
```

I'm getting output as

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 8, "day" : 15 }, "sum" : 200 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2016, "month" : 5, "day" : 20 }, "sum" : 150 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2016, "month" : 6, "day" : 29 }, "sum" : 250 }
```

I want only the records of particular year and particular month and in that month, day wise like this

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2016, "month" : 6, "day" : 28 }, "sum" : 150 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2016, "month" : 6, "day" : 29 }, "sum" : 200 }
```

I tried `$match` too

```
db.expenses.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            year: { $year: "$createdat" },
            month: { $month: "$createdat" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdat" },
            expenseprice: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $eq: ["$month", 06]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: "$year",
                month: "$month",
                day: "$day"
            },
            sum: { $sum: "$expenseprice" }
        }
    }
])
```

But I'm getting error like this

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $eq",
    "code" : 16810
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1

2016-06-29T16:20:47.754+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $eq",
    "code" : 16810
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the below sample for how the year and month in $group can be referred. As per my understanding, that is the last bit you need for your requirement.

```
db.expenses.aggregate([
   {$project: {_id:1,year:{$year:"$createdat"},month:{$month:"$createdat"}, day:{$dayOfMonth:"$createdat"},expenseprice:1}},
   {$group: {_id:{year:"$year",month:"$month",day:"$day"}, sum:{$sum:"$expenseprice"}}},
   {$match : {"_id.year" : 2016, "_id.month" : 6}}])
```

I am not sure why you have added another group after the match. From my initial understanding, it may not be required. If the above solution is not as expected, please update the comment or requirement. I will adjust the answer accordingly.

I have tested my query with some sample data. The data is filtered for a month and I get the day wise breakdown.